# Changing name servers for website only

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, nameserver

I want to change the nameservers in 123-reg so that the website points to my webserver, but the email is being hosted by someone else.

Should I leave the @ and Mail records pointing to the present email hosting provider and just update the nameservers? Or should I add my nameservers to the records also?

Answer (score 1):

Change @ and www to point your webserver(or only www, if don't use only domain name).

Do not change MX(mail) record, If you do not want to change ISP mail.

Comment: No. Don't change nasemserver. Nameserver change if you change DNS server.

Comment: the nameserver holds your records, you only need to change the records associated with what you want to happen, not the entire nameserver. You may mean A records, not nameserver in this case, that is what is associated with domain name to ip resolution.

Comment: That sounds correct.  It can take a while for the changes to propagate through the DNS caches.

Comment: Nohing has been updated and it has been over 15hrs now....never know it to take that long, so something else needs updating as the site is not pointing to me??? Any thoughts

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm getting the same problem with 123-reg :/